# can't load digits trained caffe model with opencv readnetfromcaffe

Tags: c++, caffe, opencv3.1, nvidia-digits

I've built digits from [this tutorial](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/docs/BuildDigits.md) recently, everything is ok and I finally trained my AlexNet model (also trained a SqueezNet so that I can upload the model here) ! the problem is when I download my model from Digits, I can not load it into my program for testing!I have tested my program with GoogleNet downloaded [from this link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_googlenet)   and it's working fine! 
I'm using OpenCV readNetFromCaffe  in this function to load Caffe model

```
void deepNetwork::loadModel( cv::String  model ,cv::String  weight ,string lablesPath,int ps){
patchSize=ps;
labeslPath=lablesPath;
 try
{
    net = dnn::readNetFromCaffe(weight,model);
    cerr<<"loaded succ"<<endl;
}
catch (cv::Exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;

}}
```

I get the following error loading my model

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (pbBlob.raw_data_type() ==
>   caffe::FLOAT16) in blo
>   bFromProto, file
>   /home/nvidia/build-opencv/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_im
>   porter.cpp, line 242 Exception:
>   /home/nvidia/build-opencv/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_importer 
>   .cpp:242: error: (-215) pbBlob.raw_data_type() == caffe::FLOAT16 in
>   function blo
>   bFromProto
>
> OpenCV Error: Requested object was not found (Requested blob "data"
>   not found) i
>   n setInput, file
>   /home/nvidia/build-opencv/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp, line
>   1606 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what(): 
>   /home/nvidia/build-opencv/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:1606: error: 
>   (-204) Requested blob "data" not found in function setInput
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

any help would be appreciated <3

opencv version 3.3.1 also tested on (3.3.0 ,3.4.1) same error!
testing on a system without Cuda, Cudnn or Caffe just pure c++ and OpenCv... 
but i've trained my model on a aws ec2 instance (p3.2xlarge ) with Cuda,Cudnn and caffe !

[you can download the  trained squeezNet model (.prototxt and .caffemodel) here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1vh7v9wo8blwox/20180425-104235-da56_epoch_15.0.rar?dl=0)

Comment: in what way is this question different than https://stackoverflow.com/q/49998240/1714410?

Comment: More detailed explanation maybe?

Comment: I didn't ask that question, and I'm having the same one :|

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found the problem! 
it's a version problem I have digits 6.1.1 working with nvcaffe 0.17.0  for training which is not compatible with previous Caffe and OpenCv libraries ! you have to downgrade NvCaffe to version 0.15.14 and it will open with OpenCv easily!

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV DNN model expect caffemodel in BVLC format. But, NVCaffe stores the caffe model in more efficient format which different than BVLC Caffe. 
If you want model compatible with both BVLC/Caffe as well as NVcaffe.

Add this flag in solver.prototxt
store_blobs_in_old_format = true

Please read the DIGITS NVCaffe Documentation. 
[NVCaffe Documenation - store_blobs_in_old_format](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dgx/caffe-user-guide/index.html#storeblobsold)